# Find the formula and the missing number in the series

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Given the series below, can you find its formula and hence the missing number?

> 3, -1, 7, 8, 20, 35, 43, 76, ??, 131, 159

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $76$.

because:

> $a_{n+1}=n\cdot p_n-a_n$, with $a_0=3$ and $p_n$ the $n^{th}$ prime number.
>
>  So:
>  $3-1=2=1\cdot2$
>  $-1+7=6=2\cdot3$
>  $7+8=15=3\cdot5$
>  $8+20=28=4\cdot 7$
>  etc..
>  Meaning that the missing term is $8\cdot19=152-76=76$.
>  And to check, $76+131=207=9\cdot23$.